# How do I use a pre-defined CSS style for a programmatically drawn TextField?

Tags: css, apache-flex

I have a graphical application that renders text to BitmapData - right now it's hardcoded to use a specific font, and that's fine for testing, but for production I really need it to be style-able.

The rest of the application uses specific fonts, and I want to be able to just use a stylename (the style of the font) to create a TextFormat object to pass to the text sprites embedded TextField object..

So here's the sequence now, roughly:

```
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.font = "Arial";
        format.color = 0xFF0000;
        format.size = 12;
        // tf is a previously instantiated TextField()
        tf.defaultTextFormat = format;
        tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

        tf.text = _text;
```

Then later, it's simply drawn with:

```
        bmpData.fillRect(srcRect,0x00000000);
        bmpData.draw(tf);
```

Now this is nasty, so how do I get a StyleSheet or TextFormat from my apps css definitions? I've looked in the StyleManager, the CSSStyleDeclaration, nothing seems to quite fit. What's the sequence here, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following

If you set something in your CSS file called TextFormat.

```
var css:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("TextFormat")
yourComponent.setStyle("textAlign", getStyle("headerTextAlign"));
yourComponent.setStyle("fontFamily", getStyle("fontFamily"));
```

This should do what you’re looking for.

Comment: What is the `css` var used for?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can just add `[style]` metadata tags to your custom class to define your custom style properties, specify values for those properties in your css, and use `getStyle("myCustomStylePropertyName")` in your code to get the values set in the css.

See [Flex 3 help: Example: Creating style properties](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinstyle_3.html) for more info.